# Distance between spigot and bag in BIAB setup with pump

Tags: kettle, biab, pump

I'm planning on taking the step from extract brewing to all grain with BIAB. 
My plan is to buy a [induction hob](http://www.bryggselv.no/products/induksjonsplate-pro-3500w), 15 gal [kettle](http://morebeer.com/view_product/8423/103458/Heavy_Duty_Brew_Kettle_-_With_Ball_Valve_60_Quart_15_Gallon) and a [March pump](http://morebeer.com/view_product/17330/102345/March_Pump_-_Polysulphone__230V).

Will i need some kind of spacer to keep the bag out of the spigot when i turn on the pump?

Comment: What is the pump for? Most instructions I've seen for BIAB is mash and boil in the same vessel, so the liquid doesn't need to go anywhere until post-boil. Regardless, a false bottom should solve this problem.

Comment: The pump is to recirculate to keep a even temperature inside and outside the bag. I'm planing to make a system to control the temperature like the Braumeister systems have.

Comment: Cool idea as it will give you a little more mash control, generate clearer wort and likely increase efficiency a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas for you, with the caveat that I have no direct experience with pumps + BIAB, I'm just spitballing here.

A false bottom will keep your bag off the kettle floor and away from the outlet. I couldn't easily see if MoreBeer makes a false bottom to fit that particular kettle, but there's probably a generic product that will fit reasonably well.

A screen on the kettle outlet will prevent the bag from being sucked directly in. I use a tube screen on my kettle to keep loose hops out when I drain the wort, the same should work just as well for maintaining even liquid flow through the bag to the outlet.